# Joining a hexagon mesh with a circle mesh with faces: is there an easier way than what I'm currently doing?

Tags: faces, subdivision-surface

I hope all is well. I have a quick question regarding joining a hexagon and a circle with faces. First, here's how I've been doing it:

Either subdividing the hexagon sides to produce enough vertices to allow for a 1:1 match with those of the circle, or doing it the other way around, or, if that's not possible, finding the smallest common multiple of both.

Is there another way around doing this?

[image]

Comment: Please show some screenshots, thanks   ;)

Comment: No problem, I'll add it in.

Comment: This looks like the right way of doing it. You are using the Bridge tool right? Not linking each vertices one by one?

Comment: I'm doing them 1 by 1 :( I didn't know the bridge tool existed. Thank you for that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sometimes it might be less fiddly to *create* the circle from a subdivided hexagon, by <kbd>I</kbd> insetting the hexagon, and then using either the shipped add-on Loop Tools > Circle operation, or <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> 'To Sphere'. You could always snap-scale the inner circle to connect it to another existing one, if that's the intention.

[image]

.. and you could do it to multiple hexagons at once